# Where can I download Shark?

Tags: iphone, ios, profiler, shark

This is probably a rather dumb question but I've been looking around the Apple developer pages and I haven't found any download link to shark. I did a search on my hard drive and I only found shark plugins...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shark has been replaced by instruments with iOS4.

<strike>Also have a look at [this article](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tech-news/apple-profiling-tools-shark-is-out-instruments-is-in)</strike>

Answer (score 2):

You can still find CHUD 4.6.2 on [connect.apple.com](http://connect.apple.com) under "Developer Tools".

Comment: Site unreachable

Answer (score -1):

According to the wikipedia page:

"Since Mac OS X 10.7, it is not on the Apple site any more and was replaced by Instruments."